# Is "adjective+plural noun+noun" a valid grammatical structure?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

There are many instances in the English language that we want to use a noun as a modifier but we want that noun to specify a number of things rather than just one.

As an example, I want to say that there is a particular group that is responsible for supervising all English journals published by a university.

Is it grammatically correct to write "English Journals Group"? Even though we know that modifying nouns should be used in their singular form.

Comment: automatic weapons ban, dry goods store

Comment: Some more context is needed. If you write "English Journals Group", since it is capitalized it would be considered a title so it is what it is. If you mean "a group of English journals", then "English journals group". If you mean a "group that belongs to English Journals" (realizing this does not make a lot of sense) then "English journals' group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be acceptable.  Compare "recent graduate**s** association".